# Collection of isometries between two Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose that we have two Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ which are isometric. What can we say about the collection of all isometries between $M$ and $N$? Is it a group? Do all the element have a specific form?

Comment: You have no natural composition, so no natural group structure. Any (bijective) isometry between $M$ and $N$ induces a bijection of $\operatorname{Iso}(M,N)$ with $\operatorname{Iso}(M)$ or $\operatorname{Iso}(N)$, however, and the isometry groups of $M$ resp. $N$ carry a natural group structure.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Given an isometry $\phi:M \rightarrow N$ how do I construct the bijection $\Phi: Iso(M,N) \rightarrow Iso(N)$? Can you recommend a reference?

Comment: $\Phi(\psi) = \psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ for example. $\alpha \mapsto \phi\circ\alpha\circ\phi^{-1}$ is the induced isomorphism between $\operatorname{Iso}(M)$ and $\operatorname{Iso}(N)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it into a group in a non-canonical way, by fixing one isometry $f:M\to N$ and pretending it to be the identity map. Then we can think of manifolds as being the same manifold, on which the isometries naturally form a group. In original terms, this group operation between the elements of $\operatorname{Isom}(M,N)$ is 
$$g*h = g\circ f^{-1}\circ h$$

> Do all the element have a specific form?

If $M$ and $N$ have specific form, an you apply sufficient effort toward identification of isometries, you may be able to determine the form of all isometries. As examples, the Euclidean space, sphere, and hyperbolic space have rich, explicitly described, groups of isometries. On the other hand, if you take some arbitrary smooth function $u:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$  and ask what the isometries of $(\mathbb R^n, e^{2u}dx^2)$ are, no concrete answer can be given without looking at $u$ closely.